# Avoiding screen flickering when one theme is disabled and another enabled (inhibit redraw???)

Tags: colors, inhibit, event-sequence

Is it possible to temporarily disable buffer (and frame) redraws? I particuarly mean situation, when I disable some theme and enable another one, and would like to avoid a moment when emacs flashes with white background.

**Illustration**

To prepare, load any two dark themes in any way you like. For example eval the following snippet (I use twilight and molokai but any dark themes will do):

```
(load-theme 'twilight 't 't) 
(load-theme 'molokai 't 't)
(enable-theme 'twilight)
```

Then simulate actual problem: try eval-ing that:

```
(disable-theme 'twilight)
(enable-theme 'molokai)
```

at least in my case Emacs redraws itself in white before picking new colors, what causes unpleasant screen flash. Before you ask: reversing the order (enabling new before disabling old) does not help, in fact it sometimes flashes twice.

**Solution???**

I look for tricks like

```
(let ((inhibit-something-to-keep-emacs-from-repainting))
   (disable-theme 'twilight)
   (enable-theme 'molokai))
```

or maybe for another way to reload themes.

PS inhibit-redisplay, whatever it is, does not seem to help.

Comment: I don't have an answer for avoiding it, but please consider reporting it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: What Emacs version are you on? IIRC it's gotten better in 24.4.

Comment: I use 24.3.1 (this is what I got on Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: I installed 24.4.1, things did not change much (well, maybe it goes somewhat faster, but there still is a white flash).

Comment: (as a complete sidenote, I am happy to upgrade as I can type → in emacs again – dead key works again, I missed it so much...)